# How create link which don't handling in controller? Spring framework

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web

I just want create simple link like [test](/spring/test.html) and this link should not handling in controller(work like simple link in html).But in Spring every link handling in controller which I don't want. I know that I can put my test.html page in static resources(beyond folder WEB-INF) and controller don't handling this request, but I find another solution

this part of my web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Comment: so your problem is every link pass for the cmaontroller? can u show me some code from view? maybe i can help u.

Comment: What version of Spring are you using?

Comment: here my project on git https://github.com/victortylikov/uZability and I need create link from index.jsp to 01_uxpeople.jsp (i do like this <a class="new_read" href="/spring/views/articles/01_uxpeople.jsp">Читать дальше...</a> but it don't work)

Comment: this is picture of tree of my project http://www.image123.net/egwnsd53fk4kpic.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can map a url directly to a view (assuming your `ViewResolver` is correctly setup) surpassing and without the need of an intermediate `Controller`.

**XML config sample**

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/test" view-name="test"/>
```

**Java config sample**

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
//..

  @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/test").setViewName("test");
    }
//..
}
```

Comment: But if I have many links which don't need to be handling in controller this mean that I should add links in this class? like setViewName("Name of direct link")

Comment: When there is no Controller logic and you need to map url directly to view then yes you needs an entry for each such mapping. Do some googling for "mvc:view-controller" to see some overall examples.

Comment: thanks, use only xml config-all works fine!And how I understand I can use xml config or java code?

Comment: glad it did what you wanted. For java spring config you'll have to do some readup and searching before migrating part or all of your existing config into it.